# Spring boot 2.3.5 migration problems - only in my local environment

Tags: spring-boot

We migrated from the 2.3.4 to 2.3.5 spring boot version. Everything works fine except when I run the project on my own machine. I could run the project with the 2.3.4 version but it couldn't resolve beans dependences with the 2.3.5 version. If I run my own project in another environment it works fine.
Local configuration:
Java SE 11.0.10
Apache Maven 3.8.1
mac os x", version: "10.15.7", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Any idea what's going on?
I reinstalled all.

Error: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name ‘XXXXX’ defined in file [XXXX.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name ‘XX’ defined in class path resource.

The pom file is the same in each case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>XXXX</artifactId>
    <name>XXXX</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <groupId>XXXXX</groupId>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.3.5.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <maven-pmd-plugin.version>3.13.0</maven-pmd-plugin.version>
    <maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>
    <io.springfox.version>2.9.2</io.springfox.version>
    <jacoco-maven.version>0.8.5</jacoco-maven.version>
    <swagger-annotations.version>2.1.2</swagger-annotations.version>
    <springdoc-openapi-ui.version>1.4.3</springdoc-openapi-ui.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- OPENAPI 3.0 libs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springdoc-openapi-ui.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger-annotations.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco-maven.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-pmd-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>validate</id>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-pmd-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>validate</id>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce-property</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-group</id>
        <url>https://XXXXX</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Thanks.
Regards

Comment: Can you share your config file (pom.xml etc) and some logs showing the errors?

Comment: I edited the original message with the required information. The same pom with 2.3.4.RELEASE works correctly. Thanks